# Javascript filter out substring elements in an array

Tags: javascript

Is there a way, ideally using higher order functions, to filter out the repeating substring elements in an array? For example:

```
var obj = ["a", "a.b.c", "a.b", "a.e", "a.b.d"]
```

to become

```
["a.b.c", "a.e", "a.b.d"] //since both "a" and "a.b" appear inside either "a.b.c" or "a.b.d".
```

The solution will probably require Hashtables or Sets but I am not sure how to get started.

Comment: So you are wanting the longest repeat of a substring, not the first, correct? Hence why you favored "a.b.c" over "a.b" or "a", yes?

Comment: @mhodges Yes, because "a.b.c" contains "a.b" AND "a" in it already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use a `filter()` and `find()` combination along with a Set to remove duplicates

```js
var data = ["a", "a.b.c", "a.b", "a.e", "a.b.d"];

var res = [...new Set(data)].filter(val => !data.find(s => s !== val && s.startsWith(val)));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the array `.reduce` function to do this.

Just see if your current string is a substring of something already in the array, and ignore it if so. Otherwise, if something in the array is a substring of the current string, replace it. And finally, if neither is the case, add the current string to the array:

```js
var obj = ["a", "a.b.c", "a.b", "a.e", "a.b.d"]

var result = obj.reduce((deduped, item) => {
  if (deduped.some(s => s.includes(item))) return deduped;
  
  const replace = deduped.findIndex(s => item.includes(s));
  if (replace !== -1) {
    deduped.splice(replace, 1, item)
  } else {
    deduped.push(item)
  }
  
  return deduped;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is using the function `filter` to get the desired elements, the function `some` to check at least one match and the function `includes` to check if the current element is a substring.

*This approach finds a substring to identify a match.*

```js
var obj = ["a", "a.b.c", "a.b", "a.e", "a.b.d"],
    filtered = obj.filter((element, i, arr) => !arr.some((o, oi) => {
      return oi === i ? false : o.includes(element);
    }));

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```